# Google App Engine Standard Java breaks code with Unicode characters on deploy

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, google-app-engine, angularjs-material

My application is a GAE Standard Java app which uses AngularJS on client side.

My client code is minified in a JS file. I use the unicode character `✔` (\u2714) a few times in AngularJS Material Toasts. When I deploy my app using Eclipse, and access the app, inspecting the code I can see that every `✔` character has been converted to `âœ”`.

I have tried to rewrite every `✔` by its unicode JavaScript representation (\u2714) but it doesn't work either.

What is breaking my code?

Comment: The minified file is UTF-8 encoded and \u2714 is a part of that encoding, so it should work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was related with Java version. Once I updated from using Java 7 to Java 8, the minified file was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Are you serving the file as a static file or via a request handler?

Regardless you should use something like font awesome for icons like check marks: https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid

You would just need to put this `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` in the template for your Material Toast (along with importing font-awesome `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css">`)